# how to add zxing barcodescanner to windows phone 8 cordova phonegap application

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, zxing

Am using windows 'visual studio express 2012 for windows phone' and need to some tips on how to add zxing to my cordova phonegap application.

I've successfully written an application on android using the zxing barcode scanner but am struggling with how to add the zxing barcodescanner using windows in a cordova phonegap app.

Any help or guidance would be great, thanks

Comment: Are you using Phonegap/Cordova 3 or above, or below?

Comment: Am using version 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

OK - since it's 2.9.0, download/`git clone` the files from the following location:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/WindowsPhone/BarcodeScanner/deploy

Once you have obtained those, then you'll need to:

1. Add the two DLLs as references to your project (right-click on References under the project in VS2012 - Add New Reference - Browse for these two DLLs
2. Include the C# file in the org.apache.cordova directory.
3. Include the JS file in your www folder.
4. Update config.xml to map the plugin to your class - this is used in the JS file so Cordova knows which class to call.

Run it and call the scan method - and you should begin scanning!

If you require further help, let me know - but you should get the gist of what's required from here.

Edit: BTW you might want to clone that directory to your own - that is deprecated, and I could not find the WP8 barcode scanner anywhere else - thus, it's wise to obtain that before the guys at Cordova remove it.